# How to create different URL of a Single page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, cms-pages

How can i make different url of a single page

Answer (score 2):

You can create different URLs for a single page by using URL rewrites:

1. Go to the Magento 2 admin panel and navigate to Marketing > SEO & Search > URL Rewrites.
2. Click on the "Add URL Rewrite" button to create a new rewrite.
3. Select "Custom" as the URL Rewrite Type.
4. Select the Store you want to apply this rewrite to.
5. In the Request Path field, enter the new URL key you want to use for the page. i.e. `who-we-are`
6. In the Target Path field, enter the original URL of the page you want to create a different URL for. i.e. `about-us`
7. Keep Redirect Type to `No`
8. Click on the "Save" button to save the URL rewrite.
9. To test the new URL, you can open your web browser and enter the new URL `<your-site-url>/who-we-are`, you will see **about-us** page content there.

For More Detail check this [URL redirects](https://www.simicart.com/blog/create-url-redirect-magento/#:%7E:text=Using%20the%20built%2Din%20URL,Click%20on%20Add%20URL%20Rewrite.)

Cheers!